# Test logged in user has correct id in Laravel 4

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to work out how to test that the logged in user in Laravel 4 can visit the correct user account.

At the moment this is what is in my routes.php file.

```
Route::get('user/{id}', array('before' => 'auth', function(){
    // logged in user
    // but can visit any account!!
}));
```

How would I restrict this to so user/1 could only see the profile if that is the current logged in users id?

```
Auth::user()->id
```

Returns the logged in id to test against but I can't work out how to write a filter that checks it's equal to the {id} in the url.

Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Got some help through the Laravel irc channel.

This is the way I have gone with.

```
Route::filter('user', function($route, $request)
{
    if( $request->segment(2) != Auth::user()->id)
    {
        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }
});
```

Then on my route do.

```
Route::get('user/{id}', array('before' => 'auth|user', 'uses' => 'UsersController@index'));
```