# Don't show the URL's parameters in Laravel 4.1

Tags: laravel-4

I have a CRUD for Users in Laravel 4.1
When the user want see his data, the url is: mydomain.com/public/users/3 (the show method).

How I can hide the id "3" in the url? So, if the number is visible, the user can see the data of other users (as 4,5 or others id)?

Thanks

In my filter.php I have:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{   
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
});
```

Comment: you could define a filter, that only the logged user may call this route

Comment: how could I do that?

Comment: I think this is the solution to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737491/test-logged-in-user-has-correct-id-in-laravel-4

Comment: so, delete this question then ;-)

Comment: Don't really need to delete the question, you could also post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I can't resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved.

In UserController.php:

```
public function show()
{
    //
    $usuario = Auth::user();

    // show the view and pass the nerd to it
    return View::make('users.show')
        ->with('elusuario', $usuario);
}
```

In show.blade.php

```
@extends ("layout/layout")

@section ("principal")

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('nombre', 'Nombre') }}
            {{ Form::text('nombre',null, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>$elusuario->nombre,'disabled'=>'disabled')) }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
            {{ Form::email('email',null, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>$elusuario->email,'disabled'=>'disabled')) }}
        </div>


        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('users/' . $elusuario->id . '/edit') }}">Modificar datos</a>

@stop
```

That solved the issue and the url don't show the id of user. Simply called as mydomain.com/public/users/perfil and has the data (id, name, etc) from session variable.